# What kind of font(s) offer maximum on-screen readability for consumption on smartphones in Africa?

Tags: font

I know that Africa is very large and very diverse, a continent and not anything like a single country, and cell phone hardware is presumably not uniform.

However, if it is known, what kind of font(s) would be optimal for ebooks intended for consumption on smartphones in Africa?

Comment: Why would you expect fonts to appear different in Africa vs other places.  How are the phones different?

Comment: In many third world settings, people continue to use desktop computers that in the first world would be found primarily in museums. There is less of a concept of obsolesence, unless marketing is getting people to chase after the newest model: an iPhone 1 and an iPhone X may be much less distinguished than in the first world. I would expect a wider range of generations and ages of cell phones than is expected where a professional can quite possibly afford to have the newest version of the gadget. In general, it has been observed worldwide that there's a broader computer age span in poor lands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Readability is more than just changing the font. A good font in one setting may be a poor font in another. Since you don't know the specific characteristics of the devices your users will be using, **consider using the default font installed on the device.** It should work well enough for any purpose.

If you must have a custom font, offer it alongside the default. Some fonts to consider:

- [Noto](https://www.google.com/get/noto/). Contains broad support for multiple languages.
- [Literata](https://github.com/googlefonts/literata/releases). Designed for use with ebooks.